# operational error: no such table django Every Time I create models

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.0, Python

Every Time I am creating new Model when I do

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

it shows `no changes detected` and on migrate `no migrations to apply`

Even I tried

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations home
```

shows

```
Migrations for 'home':
  home/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model FAQ
    - Create model Topic
```

and then on

```
python3 manage.py migrate home
```

It still shows

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: home
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

and when I try to open that table in admin.

it shows

```
OperationalError at /admin/home/faq/
no such table: home_faq
```

however it'd worked when I'd deleted migrations and database and re migrated everything.

But I can't delete everything Every Time.

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_title = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    topic_discription = models.TextField()
    no_of_posts = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic_title

class FAQ(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=800,unique=True)
    answer = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author_info = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

I've registered it on admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Topic,FAQ
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Topic)
admin.site.register(FAQ)
```

EDIT #1:

Okay now I cleared all migrations and db.sqlite3 and ran

```
# python3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
# python3 manage.py makemigrations home
Migrations for 'home':
  home/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model FAQ
    - Create model Topic
# python3 manage.py migrate home
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: home
Running migrations:
  Applying home.0001_initial... OK
```

It does work but I rebuild the database for that.

Because It's not in production yet so its okay but It may become big problem later.

thing to notice is on

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

It shows

```
No changes detected
```

but created migrations when

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations home
```

and have friendly response on

```
python3 manage.py migrate home
```

So even if there is any way to force rebuild the model in db then could do.( python3 manage.py *force* migrate )

^ Could be possible solution. if there exist *force*

EDIT #2:

Installed Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'UserProfile.apps.UserprofileConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: you had this problem because you deleted the table in your db (the models you were trying to add were columns inside this tabel) that's why you had this problem  . you wont get this problem again as long as you dont delete the table,

Comment: Is it possible that you dont have the app `home` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in **settings.py**?

Comment: @Krystofee It worked when he deleted the migrations wich means he already have the app inside INSTALLED_APPS and had a table already created as you can see in his Migration file